# Flex Pan & Zoom with vector images

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I've looked at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom/ for pan & zoom, and it does a very good job of it.  However, it only works with raster images.  Does anyone know how to modify this for vector images (SVG converted to SWF).

My limited attempts have not gone well, as the Imageviewer.as class is clearly designed around bitmaps.

I can load the SVG images in an Image, but I'd really like to pan & zoom too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [OpenZoom](http://openzoom.org/)? AFAIK it supports anything that can be loaded on the stage.